# Which particle rolls faster? Is the speed of the particles which are rolling differs with their shape?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy

A solid disk and a solid sphere each of them has the same mass and same kinetic energies, which one is faster?

Comment: I wish to emphasize what John said below: we ***don't*** do homework here. Please ask about concepts.

Answer (score 0):

As with your previous question, [How we can find the kinetic energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31954), we can't just answer homework questions but we can discuss how to go about solving them.

The disk and sphere have the same kinetic energy due to translation (bulk motion in space), so it's just the energy of rotation that's different. The disk and sphere will have different angular velocities because for the same mass they have different radii. Also the expressions for the angular kinetic energy are different. As before, a quick Google will find the you relevant equations. Ask here if you still run into difficulties.

Comment: Good answer, and good job addressing the question at the conceptual level. I hope you don't mind my tweaking the language a bit.